# How to style forms in the Zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I really like the idea of putting forms into a seperate class that manages validation etc, but I don't like everything ending up in a DL and also not being able to use square bracket notation in post elements like `<input type='checkbox' name='data[]'>`.

Is there another way of generating forms - like in views so I can style them the way I want, but also keeping the validation aspect? Also how would I load this view into my current view (using partial view somehow?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest going with the full out form ViewScript to manage how your form elements are displayed.

For example, if you wanted them displayed as list items you would have a form that look like this

```
<?php
class Default_Form_Myform extends Zend_Form
{
    public function  __construct($options = null) {
        parent::__construct($options);
    }
    public function  init() {
        parent::init();
        $this->setName('myform');
        $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
        $name->setLabel('Name')
                    ->setDescription('Give your name...');
        $this->addElement($name);            
        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $this->addElement($submit);        
        $this->clearDecorators();
        $this->setElementDecorators(
                array(
                    'viewHelper',
                    'Errors',
                    array('Label', array('class' => 'delabel')),
                    'Description',
                    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'li')),        
                )
        );           
        // The template is at application/modules/default/views/myForm.phtml
        $this->setDecorators(array(
        array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'myForm.phtml'))
        ));  
    }
}
```

Then you would have a template at `application/modules/default/views/myForm.phtml`

*All elements are called by their declared name like `$this->element->name`*

```
<form action="<?= $this->element->getAction(); ?>"
      method="<?= $this->element->getMethod(); ?>"
      enctype="<?= $this->element->getEnctype(); ?>"
      name="<?= $this->element->getName(); ?>">
    <ul>
    <?= $this->element->name; ?>
    <?= $this->element->submit ?>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Now in your view script you just need to echo the form like you normally would `<?= $this->form; ?>`

**Note I'm using modules, you may or may not have that in the directories and class names**

### Please consider accepting answers to your questions...

it makes it worth while for those that answer.

Comment: I really like this mechanism for displaying forms - its pretty cool!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a form "decorator". Check out this tutorial: http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450

EDIT: Link dead as of June 2015. Looks like [link moved here](http://devzone.zend.com/1240/decorators-with-zend_form/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array notation with Zend_Form : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html

You can remove the DL by setting your own decorators.

Answer (score 0):

Decorators are awesome once you get the hang of them.

But if you prefer, you can manually create "templates" for your form using the [ViewScript Decorator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.viewScript).